# Unable to unalias rm and let it to be a function in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I run unsuccessfully in my .zshrc

```
unalias rm  
rm() { mv $* /tmp/wastebasket }
```

I get at the startup

```
/Users/Masi/.zshrc:unalias:34: no such hash table element: rm
```

I noticed that the hash table problem has been an unresolved bug in [Ubuntu](http://qa.ubuntu.com/reports/launchpad-database/unfixed-bugs-with-patches.html) for run-help.
I am not sure whether the bug applies to Mac and to `rm` -command too.

**How can you get the notification off at the startup?**

Comment: make that `mv -- "$@"` instead of `$*` and it'll work for all sorts of funky file names, too.

Comment: If the alias is changing the behavior, have a different name: eg. `thrash` or `clean`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everyone else is right that you simply didn't have an alias.  More importantly:

**DON'T** do this.  Some day you will be at another POSIX machine that follows POSIX standards (deleting without "recycling"), and you will casually delete something and have no way to undo it.  Learn rm discipline now.

Comment: I agree. Learn to use rm wisely, and don't rely on any safety net you may be able to set up for yourself.

Comment: @Matt: I will follow your tip. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: As a follow-up, if you're concerned about this, you can get in the habit of running `rm -i`.  Again, don't alias `rm` to `rm -i`, for the same reason (you'll eventually run `rm` without the alias).

Answer (score 2):

You should only try to remove an alias that exists.
Creating an alias that is unaliased right away strikes me as ugly.
My recommendation is to test for rm being an alias and unaliasing if so.

```
 case $(type rm) in
     (*alias*) unalias rm;;
 esac
```

Or use brute force and ignore stderr with

```
 unalias rm 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

That error message is because you're trying to unalias `rm` and there is no such alias.

Since you can alias something more than once without an error, I would change your code to be:

```
alias rm=x
unalias rm  
rm() { mv $* /tmp/wastebasket }
```

That guarantees that `rm` exists as an alias before you try to unalias it.

Comment: make that `mv -- "$@"` instead of `$*` and it'll work for all sorts of funky file names, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with zsh, but perhaps it is because rm is not an alias, but is actually a standard utility residing in /bin.

You could just alias it without attempting to unalias it first, overriding any previous alias.